# Is there a sorting algorithm that minimizes last-value reuse while maintaining efficient time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, optimization, computer-science

I'm exploring sorting algorithms where there's a frequent reuse of comparison values. For instance, in quicksort, a pivot value often results in comparisons like (23, 5), (23, 18), (23, 44), etc. I'm interested in an algorithm that optimizes for a low rate of reuse while also maintaining an efficient time complexity.

**Example:**

Consider a comparison sequence like A vs B, B vs C, C vs D, A vs E. Here, the value B is reused from the first comparison to the second, and C from the second to the third. This algorithm would have a reuse rate of r = .5, since 2/4 comparisons were reuses.

**Question:**

1. Are there existing sorting algorithms that inherently minimize this last-value reuse while maintaining efficiency?
2. If not, what modifications could be suggested for standard algorithms (like quicksort, merge sort, etc.) to achieve this?

I tested a few sorting algorithms on their reuse rate (r). Bubble, quick, and insertion sort both had r values at around .9, meaning each comparison shared a value with the previous comparison ~90% of the time. Shell sort (r = .4), comb sort (r = .35), and tournament sort (r = .15) had the lowest, though shell sort outperformed the others in number of comparisons.

Comment: FWIW, that seems counterintuitive to me: other things being equal, wouldn't favoring the reuse of a compare operand tend to be the most efficient approach?

Comment: Yes, the reuse of a compare operand would be more efficient, which is probably why it's so hard to find preexisting algorithms with low values.

Comment: In any comparison sort algorithm you could add the check whether you are about to perform a comparison that is a reuse. If so, there are at most three indices involved (the two of the last comparison, and the two of the planned comparison, minus one that is reused). Perform a dummy comparison between two indices that are not among these three (this only works if the array has at least 5 elements). Then perform the planned comparison. This at most doubles the number of comparisons, so a O(log) algorithm will still be O(log). It does not prevent reuse of values when array has duplicates.

Comment: I think that @trincot has the most practical approach. If you don't want useless compares, then I would suggest taking advantage of the fact that mergesort has a lot of parallelizable and hence easy to reorder work in it. And interleaving unrelated merges will avoid reused comparisons.